# Proof that no integers satisfy $x^2+2y^2 = p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Suppose $p$ is a prime such that $p\equiv 5,7 \ \pmod{8}$, then I want to show that there exist no integral solutions $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+2y^2=p$.

I did a simple approach of simply computing with $x,y=0,1,....7$. But I want to know a more technical approach with a good explanation. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Hint:  Since $p$ is odd, $x$ is odd, which directly gives $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.  Then what can you say about $2y^2 = p - x^2$?

Comment: I think the lone *Vote to Close* is premature, considering that user [dearth](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/803690) is a *New contributor*.

Comment: And I would not close anyway.  The OP showed what work he did and asked a specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**  Since $p$ is odd, $x$ is odd, which directly gives $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.  Then what can you say about $$2y^2 = p - x^2?$$

Comment: I got it. Since x is odd we have two cases 1) both x and y are odd 2) x is odd and y is even       in the first case the equation becomes 1+2 = 3(mod 8)  and in the second case the equation becomes 1+0= 1(mod 8) and therefore I got the answer. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @dearth, you are welcome!  If you think this answer is helpful, you may accept it by clicking on the **Check** mark.